# How to return a nested json value with boto3

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Using python3, boto3, with AWS.  Trying to specify the return to one value instead of all that come back normally.

I have:

```
response = ec2client.describe_network_acls()
print(response["Associations"])
```

I get all three associations back:

```
[{'NetworkAclId': 'acl-58***221', 'NetworkAclAssociationId': 'aclassoc-267***56', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-e5###6bf'}, {'NetworkAclId': 'acl-5823###1', 'NetworkAclAssociationId': 'aclassoc-0a2###7a', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-ec0c###4'}]
```

But, I would like to just get the `subnet id`.

Thanks in advance, any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: acl["Associations"] is an array.. so you should run for each object and print the `SubnetId`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import boto3

ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_network_acls()

for acl in response['NetworkAcls']:
    for association in acl['Associations']:
        print(association['SubnetId'])
```

The trick is to look at the sample output in the boto3 documentation to determine available fields and lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
response = ec2client.describe_network_acls()
subnet_ids = list(map(lambda assoc: assoc["SubnetId"], response))
print(subnet_ids)
```

If you need the code